# How to pass an array of parameters to MySql select ... in

Tags: mysql

I wish to select an array of records with id 2, 4, 6 from a mysql database file. I am trying to pass an array of integers to a Mysql store procedure. But I fail to create a working stored procedure.

Would you help me compose one?

This is the C# code

```
   public static List<PhotoComment> GetPhotos(int[] _ids)
    {
        MySqlConnection _con = Generals.GetConnnection();
        List<PhotoComment> _comments = new List<PhotoComment>();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand _cmd = new MySqlCommand("Photos_GetPhotosByIDs", _con);
            _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_ids", _ids);

            _con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader _reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (_reader.Read())
            {
                PhotoComment _comment = new PhotoComment(_reader.GetInt32("cID"), _reader.GetInt32("cFID"), _reader.GetString("cUser"), _reader.GetString("cContent"), _reader.GetDateTime("cDate"), _reader.GetBoolean("cChecked"));
                _comments.Add(_comment);
            }
            _con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception _ex)
        {
            _con.Close();
            ReportMgr.ReportException(_ex.Message);
        }
        return _comments;
    }
```

this is the mysql

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Photos_GetPhotosByIDs`(in _ids int[])

BEGIN

select * from tbl_photos where ID in _ids;

END

Comment: Can you share any code with us?

Answer (score 0):

There are no array types in MySQL. You can use table (temporary table) instead. Fill the bale with id values and join tables to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting your question right but what I think you're asking is how to send multiple values into an input parameter of a stored procedure.

If that's what you're asking, the following link may help. Not sure if such a feature exists in MySql but in SQL Server, it's called "Table-Valued Parameters" - TVP in short.

TVP allows you to pass multiple values into a single input parameter. Hope this helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx